# How do I speed up this 1.7 Second Mysql Query?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I'm writing a webapp in PHP where a list of users can be voted on.  The query I'm using to pull a user from the table is quite slow.  I suspect there is a much more efficient way to check if the target user has already been voted on by the active user.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT ratedid
    FROM votes
    WHERE who LIKE 12707264
)
AND picture1 NOT LIKE  ''
AND cp1 <  '10'
AND gender NOT LIKE  'male'
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 1
```

Table data as follows:

```
>SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
>SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `notchus_userdb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `bio` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `picture1` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cp1` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture2` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `picture3` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `friends` blob,
  `relationship_status` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `relationship_interest` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `verified` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `birthday` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hometown` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `citylocation` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `oauth_provider` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `oauth_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ratchet` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boss` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isadmin` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `views` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `reviews` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `isuser` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


Server version: 5.1.70-cll
-- PHP Version: 5.3.17

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `notchus_userdb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `votes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
  `uqid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `picture` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ratedid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quote` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `who` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `votedate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `control` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uqid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1084 ;
```

Comment: Please post an EXPLAIN

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, LIKE is only for doing wildcard matching.  I'm surprised that you're not getting an error doing a LIKE on an integer.  Then again, nothing MySQL does surprises me.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT ratedid
    FROM votes
    WHERE who = 12707264
)
AND picture1 <> ''
AND cp1 <  '10'
AND gender <>  'male'
ORDER BY RAND( ) 
LIMIT 1
```

Also note that if it's OK for `picture1` to be an empty string, then you shouldn't have a `NOT NULL` on the column, and you should store a NULL in the column where is no picture.

Comment: Removing the likes took it from 1.7 seconds to 1.3682 Seconds. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your like statements don't appear to be using wildcards, I see no reason to use them here. Try changing them to equal signs. Indexing your tables could help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have indices on the foreign key relationships.

try:

```
create index who on votes (who);

create index q1 on users (picture1, cp1, gender);
```

Also, you appear to be confused about "like" and "=" - when comparing an integer column (e.g. CP1), use `cp1 < 1` or `who = 12707264`.

Comment: Adding these indices caused the query execution time to go from ~1.3 seconds to over 5 seconds.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Changed the votes table index to include ratedid as well as who and got it down to 0.0559 Seconds